# Can't find matching form

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am trying to use Python's mechanize module to submit a form value and download a subsequent file.  However, I keep getting an error saying the script can't find the form.

The website I'm using is [here](https://ccmis.dhs.state.ia.us/clientportal/providersearch.aspx).

I'm trying to select by County = 'Linn'.

Below is the script I have up to selecting the form...

```
import mechanize

url = 'https://ccmis.dhs.state.ia.us/clientportal/providersearch.aspx'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlSearchByLocationCounty")
```

I keep getting an error that there is no form with a matching name. When I use developer tools this is the name of the that shows.  Below is a snippet of the HTML...

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlSearchByLocationCounty" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlSearchByLocationCounty" style="width:150px;">
    <option value="">Select County</option>
    <option value="Adair">Adair</option>
    <option value="Adams">Adams</option>
    <option value="Allamakee">Allamakee</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select the form by name, ID, etc before you can select an input and set its value. Here is the updated code which sets the country to Linn. I recommend reviewing the cheat sheet at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet.

```
import mechanize

url = 'https://ccmis.dhs.state.ia.us/clientportal/providersearch.aspx'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="aspnetForm")

country = br.form.find_control("ctl00$MainContent$ddlSearchByLocationCounty")
country.value = ['Linn']
print country.value
```

Comment: Thanks pointing me in the right direction!  A couple follow-up questions.  1) Where did you find the form name to be 'aspnetForm'?  2) Once the value is set to 'Linn', there is a 'Search' button at the bottom where I'd like to proceed to the next screen.  I'm assuming I'd need to use `br.click_link/follow_link` to proceed to the next screen?

Comment: 1) I launched Google Chrome Developer Tools on the site (F12) and searched for `<form>` tag which returned `<form name="aspnetForm">`.
2) The search button is an input type button and not a link. Since there are two buttons with type="submit", Search and Clear, you need to pass extra parameters when calling `submit()`: `br.submit(name='ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch', label='Search')`

Comment: I believe I have the script setup correctly now.  I'm now wondering how I would download the report on the following screen once submitting Search?  Does a new URL need to be placed or how does that work?  The form is still called the same.  The 'Download Report' control has an id, but no name.  And the value I want is "2"...which is for Download to Excel.